# Optimum acceleration control with restricted maximum acceleration

Tags: optimization, vectors

An object is placed in a 2D Cartesian space, at position (px0, py0), with initial velocity (vx0, vy0). The object is to be moved to another position (px1, py1), with ultimate velocity (vx1, vy1). The sum of absolute acceleration on both axis |ax|+|ay| is limited at a given specified max, while the speed on both axis vx and vy have their max limit as well.

Given the above constraints, is there a relatively easy algorithm to compute a reasonably optimized trajectory? The goal is to optimize for minimum moving time. Absolute optimum solution is not needed, rather an easy to implement one is needed, as this will be implemented on a fairly resource-limited micro-controller chip.

I am by no means good at math, nor at control theory, nor at optimization theory. All I know is coding. This might be a noobish question, but if anyone has any ideas, please let me know.